# How to show Javascript array values serially to a series of <div>?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to make a website page for language test that when the user clicks the play button, the numbers of questions and the choices are shown. So I wrote this code:

```
const audioA = document.getElementById("AudioA");
const playBtn = document.getElementById("PlayBtn");

function playPartA() {
    audioA.play();
    playBtn.style.color = "#777777";
    showQuestion();
  }


function showQuestion(){
  for(let i = 0; i < 30; i++){
    $(".questionBox").append('<div class="Question"></div><div class="Options"><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>');
  } 
  $(".secondBox").append('<a href="Listening Part A.html" class="btnToPartB">Continue to Part B</a>'); 
  
  $('.Question').each(function(index){
    $(this).html("Number ");
    $(this).append(index+1);
  }); 

  $('.Options').QuesPartA.forEach(option => {
    $('.Options span').eq(0).text(option[0]);
    $('.Options span').eq(1).text(option[1]);
    $('.Options span').eq(2).text(option[2]);
    $('.Options span').eq(3).text(option[3]);
   });

  };
```

And this is the array:

```
let QuesPartA = [
  { option: [
        "She doesn't have an appointment",
        "She must live somewhere else",
        "Her apartment isn't far away",
        "Her problem is complicated",
      ],
    answer: 2
  },

  { option: [
     "There's no charge for phone calls",
     "She can call him later if she likes",
     "His phone is out of order too",
     "She can use his phone if she wants",
  ],
    answer: 1
  },
  { option: [
     "It was simpler than he'd thought",
      "It was too hard to solve",
      "He couldn't find it",
      "He solved it even though it was hard",
    ],
    answer: 3
  }
];
```

So I use `.append` to create many boxes for the answer options, then I want to put the value of the option element on that boxes. But I failed. Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating questions first and then populating each with options, you can create both at the same time by iterating thru the questions array like this.

```
function showQuestion(){
    for(let i = 0; i < QuesPartA.length; i++){
        $(".questionBox").append('<div class="Question">Number '+ parseInt(i+1) +'</div>');
        $(".questionBox").append('<div class="Options" id="optId'+ parseInt(i+1) +'">');
        QuesPartA[i]['option'].forEach(option => {
            $("#optId"+ parseInt(i+1)).append('<span>'+option +' </span><br>');  
        });
        $(".questionBox").append('</div><br>'); // end Options div
    } 
    $(".secondBox").append('<a href="Listening Part A.html" class="btnToPartB">Continue to Part B</a>'); 
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There's a problem with your code: the `<span>` does not become the child of `.Options`, but the `.questionBox`'s instead. So I can't style them as a unity. Solution: I took the `.append` of `<span>` out of the function and create another for it. It works well. Thank you!

Comment: I modified the code by assigning Id to options div and now the options do get placed in .Options .

Answer (score 1):

After you initialize the quetionBox with all 30 questions, apply below:

```
    $.each(QuesPartA,function(index,value){
         $(".questionBox").find(".Question:eq(" + index + ")").find("span:eq(0)").html(value.option[0]);
         $(".questionBox").find(".Question:eq(" + index + ")").find("span:eq(1)").html(value.option[1]);
         $(".questionBox").find(".Question:eq(" + index + ")").find("span:eq(2)").html(value.option[2]);
         $(".questionBox").find(".Question:eq(" + index + ")").find("span:eq(3)").html(value.option[3]);
});
```

Logic is simple, based on the QuesPartA array index, find the right question and right span to change its html value.

Comment: If the question list creation failed, try to make a string with all html elements, and use $('.questionBox').html(string) to create it.

Comment: Thanks, but I have found a simpler solution.